# Ubuntu: where add a script executing SQL on machine start?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, startup

Each time Ubuntu is starting I need to run a script, which is running some SQLs.
So I need run it after MySQL already started.

Where should I put such script?

Comment: SysV init, upstart or systemd?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. I have /etc/init.d/mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file sould be place in `/etc/init.d`, and a link make in `/etc/rc2.d` (assuming you are in run level 2 (see `who -r`).

The link sould be in the form `S99sql`, all files in rc2.d are run in alphabetical order.

to sum up,

create tour file in `/etc/init.d/mysqlcmd.sh`

then change directory to /etc/rc2.d ans `ln -s ../init.d/mysqlcmd.sh S99mysql`

Comment: I do not see mysql in  /etc/rc2.d
Is it okay? How can I see when it is starting?

Answer (score 0):

**systemd**

If the version of Ubuntu you're using is using `systemd` (14.04 onwards) then you could modify the `.service` file and add another script to be ran when `MySQL` is ready.

```
# vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service
```

Add another entry to:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysqld-wait-ready $MAINPID
```

by appending a semicolon and the name of your script:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysqld-wait-ready $MAINPID ; <path to my script>
```

Note that these scripts are not run using a shell, so you'll need to wrap yours in `bash` or similar if you need redirection etc.

The `mysqld-wait-ready` script does exactly what it says and waits until `mysqld` is ready to accept connections.  Your script should therefore be able to run SQL on the server.

**Upstart**

For pre-14.04 versions of Ubuntu, you could create an `upstart` conf file

```
description     "My Post-MySQL Start Script"
author "Pavel Bernshtam"

start on started mysql

task
script
    # do my stuff here
end script
```

Save the file to `/etc/init/<my script name>.conf`

More information on `upstart` scripts is available from [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job-configuration-file)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12 :(